# Very slow query, any other ways to format this with better performace?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query (I didn't write) that was working fine for a client until the table got more then a few thousand rows in it, now it's taking 40 seconds+ on only 4200 rows.

Any suggetions on how to optimize and get the same result?

I've tried a few other methods but didn't get the correct result that this slower query returned...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
  FROM `fl_events`
  WHERE id IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT (e2.id)
      FROM `fl_events` AS e1, fl_events AS e2
      WHERE e1.startdate >= now() AND e1.startdate = e2.startdate
  )
  ORDER BY `startdate`
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Do you really need the order by?, I guess you have index in your FK, right?

Comment: I think the issue may not be the query, but db setup. What indexes do you have in `fl_events`.

Comment: an EXPLAIN would tell you why it is slow.

Comment: Sorry everyone for being so generic, Lamak's answer worked perfectly and solved the issue, I didn't write the query and was unsure if there was some strange reason why it was formatted that way. I'll work on my questions formatting, I promise! I WILL NOT LET YOU GUYS DOWN AGAIN! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appart from the obvious indexes needed, I don't really get why you are joining your table with itself for choosing the `IN` condition. The `ORDER BY` is also not needed. Are you sure that your query can't be written just like this?:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
FROM `fl_events` AS e1
WHERE e1.startdate >= now()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Query ran in .002 seconds with exact same result. Sorry to make the question too generic, I'll work on that next time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rewriting the query will help.  The key to your question is "until the table got more than a few thousand rows."  This implies that important columns aren't indexed.  Prior to a certain number of records, all the data fit on a single memory block - over that point, it takes a new block.  And index is the only way to speed up the search.

first - check to see that the ID in fl_events is actually marked as a primary key.  That physically orders the records and without it you can see data corruption and occasionally super-slow results.  The use of distinct in the query makes it look like it might NOT be a unique value.  That will pose a problem.

Then, make sure to add an index on the start_date.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness is probably related to the join of the event table with itself, and possibly startdate not having an index.